# Did this SQL update statement delete records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I ran an update statement like this, last night.

```
Update a SET a.COUNTRY = c.[ISO (2)] -- Select c.*,b.[country name]
FROM Table_V2 a
JOIN [SourceDATA].[dbo].masterdata b 
ON a.Doc_Number = REPLACE(STR(TRY_CAST(b.[order number] AS INT),10),' ','0') 
AND a.SHIP_TO = REPLACE(STR(TRY_CAST(b.[ship to number] AS INT),10),' ','0') 
AND a.SOLD_TO = REPLACE(STR(TRY_CAST(b.[sold to number] AS INT),10),' ','0') 
AND a.SKU = b.[sku number]
LEFT JOIN [CountryCodes] AS c 
On 
CASE WHEN UPPER(b.[country name]) in (SELECT COUNTRY FROM CountryCodes) THEN UPPER(b.[country name])
WHEN UPPER(b.[country name]) = 'SOUTH KOREA' THEN UPPER('Korea, South')
WHEN UPPER(b.[country name]) = 'NORTH KOREA' THEN UPPER('Korea, North')
WHEN UPPER(b.[country name]) like '%PORTUGAL%' THEN UPPER('Portugal')
WHEN UPPER(b.[country name]) like '%HONG KONG%' THEN UPPER('Hong Kong (China)') 
END = UPPER(c.Country)
WHERE a.COUNTRY is null
```

where it is joining local data Table_V2 with data on another server/database (on SourceDATA server) which is aliased as "b", but only actually updating the local table, a...(I hope).

Coming back this morning, that master data table on the other server is totally empty, when normally there's at least a million records. I know that some refreshes happen with data on [today], but it's been empty for many hours and I'm getting worried that I may have accidentally deleted the data with my update statement. I'm not aware of any refreshes that delete all the data first although I supposed it's possible. Is it possible that I deleted the data by accident?

My understanding - which I was really certain was correct - is that my update statement won't touch anything from b; it only looks at it. and updates a. I'm just so worried now hoping it's all a coicidence because I've never seen b empty, and I don't think the refreshes normally take very long. Hopefully am I missing something? Could this have been me?

Comment: Some required reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Also your `JOIN` has a bit of a "code smell" to it, as it appears that the data types for the two columns, which should have a foreign key relationship aren't the same. You should review that as otherwise your query will not be SARGable with all though functions.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the tips!! I never thought of those as bad habits. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry. Your are only changing the data in table `Table_V2`. You can check if there is a trigger on it that potentially can apply additional data manipulation.

Comment: Ok...Thank you! I'll wait awhile and check again, and hope that it's just a normal refresh that I didn't notice in the past :)  At least my nerves are somewhat calmer though, ha.  I'll also check for triggers although I'm pretty sure no one here uses triggers on these things. But that's a great suggestion to double-check.

Comment: @PBJ if you are using SQL Server 2016+ it's pretty easy to create versioning of a table (if it is important) :-) of course you can use and the standard trigger solution to create changes table...Anyway, your statement is not the source of the deletion :-)

Comment: Oh ok - I'll look into versioning. Although, I don't know if I have many permissions on "b's" server or how much control I have over that. Not a bad idea to use on my own table though.  Thanks again, that makes me so happy :)